# React Context Consumer does not update with Hooks state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am using React Context Provider and Consumer in order to pass data from my `App` component to its children.

My Context is called `CurrentUserContext`. I declare it like this:

```
const CurrentUserContext = React.createContext();
```

and export it like this:

```
export default CurrentUserContext;
```

I am wrapping my `App` component with `CurrentUserContext.Provider` and passing as the `value` a stateful data I declare like this:

```
const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(null);
```

When I want a child component to use the data, I wrap it with `CurrentUserContext.Consumer`.

It all works perfectly fine, but for some reason, when I update `loggedUser` using `setLoggedUser` (in `useEffect` for example), the consumers does not get re-rendered.

Does anyone know why?

I want every time that I update `loggedUser` using `setLoggedUser`, the relevant components (the consumers) will re-render.

Does anyone know what doesn't it work?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you pass a provider with the values inside the useState?

Comment: @EsaúMorais What do you mean? I use `CurrentUserContext.Provider` in my `App` component, if that what you're asking

Comment: you can give more information

Comment: Add your `App Component` code, and one of the places you're using the context so we know what you're doing

Comment: Yeah, it'd be good to add how the provider is being used

Comment: @F.SO7 sounds like setLoggedUser maybe mutates state but without knowing what setLoggedUser does it is hard to know for sure.